# What library/client should I use to build a front end to a DynamoDB table?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

I built an Alexa skill in node.js for my wife to log events our baby does (poop, eat, sleep, etc). It stores the events in a DynamoDB table and can return the duration since the last event for her as well.

Occasionally, she logs events several hours after the fact and wants to edit the timestamp. I could write complex logic into the Alexa skill to handle this, but it'd be easier if she could simply go to a web app and edit the timestamps directly. I started building something with dynatable but it seems to only allow for read operations, not updates.

What is the easiest/fastest way/set of tools to use to get a simple front end up and running for her that would allow her to edit a DynamoDB table?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to host your front end in AWS S3 bucket. From S3 you can trigger an AWS lambda function with the values collected from front end and Lambda can communicate to DynamoDB tables.